# Locust - How do I define multiple task sets for the same user?

Tags: python-3.x, locust

Please consider the follow code:

```
class Task1(TaskSet):
    @task
    def task1_method(self):
        pass


class Task2(TaskSet):
    @task
    def task2_method(self):
        pass


class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
    tasks = [Task1, Task2]


class LoggedInUser(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost"
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
    tasks = [UserBehaviour]
```

When I execute the code above with just one user, the method `Task2.Method` never gets executed, only the method from `Task1`.

What can I do to make sure the code from both tasks gets executed for the same user?

I would like to do it this way because I want to separate the tasks into different files for better organizing the project. If that is not possible, how can I have tasks defined into different files in an way that I can have tasks defined for each od my application modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. To solve the problem I had to add a method at the end of each taskset to stop the execution of the task set:

```
  def stop(self):
    self.interrupt()
```

In addition to that, I had to change the inherited class to `SequentialTaskSet` so all tasks get executed in order.

This is the full code:

```
class Task1(SequentialTaskSet):
    @task
    def task1_method(self):
        pass
    @task
    def stop(self):
        self.interrupt()


class Task2(SequentialTaskSet):
    @task
    def task2_method(self):
        pass
    @task
    def stop(self):
        self.interrupt()


class UserBehaviour(SequentialTaskSet):
    tasks = [Task1, Task2]


class LoggedInUser(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost"
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
    tasks = [UserBehaviour]
```

Everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought this was a bug, but it is actually just as intended (although I dont really understand WHY it was implemented that way)

> One important thing to know about TaskSets is that they will never
> stop executing their tasks, and hand over execution back to their
> parent User/TaskSet, by themselves. This has to be done by the
> developer by calling the TaskSet.interrupt() method.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#interrupting-a-taskset

I would solve this issue with inheritance: Define a base TaskSet or User class that has the common tasks, and then subclass it, adding the user-type-specific tasks/code.

If you define a base User class, remember to set `abstract = True` if you dont want Locust to run that user as well.